# How to configure logback to skip all logging messages from one class?

Tags: java, logging, logback

Somebody have maybe any idea how can I configure logback to skip all log messages from loggers from one class, for example `org.package.SpecialClass`?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like

```
<logger name="org.package.SpecialClass" level="off" />
```